# Find function signature in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash

Given a .so file and function name, is there any simple way to find the function's signature through bash?

Return example:

```
@_ZN9CCSPlayer10SwitchTeamEi
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My compiler mangles things a little different to yours (OSX g++) but changing your leading @ to an underscore and passing the result to c++filt gives me the result that I think you want:

```
bash> echo __ZN9CCSPlayer10SwitchTeamEi | c++filt
CCSPlayer::SwitchTeam(int)
```

doing the reverse is trickier as CCSPlayer could be a namespace or a class (and I suspect they're mangled differently). However since you have the .so you can do this:

```
bash> nm library.so | c++filt | grep CCSPlayer::SwitchTeam
000ca120 S CCSPlayer::SwitchTeam
bash> nm library.so | grep 000ca120
000ca120 S __ZN9CCSPlayer10SwitchTeamEi
```

Though you might need to be a bit careful about getting some extra results. ( There are some funny symbols in those .so files sometimes)

Comment: No, I want my input to be `SwitchTeam` and output `@_ZN9CCSPlayer10SwitchTeamEi`

Comment: Or simply `c++filt __ZN9CCSPlayer10SwitchTeamEi`

Comment: Keep in mind that the arguments (and class , in case of a member function) are part of a C++ function signature. There might be many results for `SwitchTeam` if the function is overloaded (or inherited)

Answer (score 2):

nm has a useful --demangle flag that can demangle your .so all at once

```
nm --demangle library.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
strings <library.so>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nm -D library.so | grep FuncName
```